# Turtle gives WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state and doesn't print

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics, nssecurecoding

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy_the_turtle = Turtle()

timmy_the_turtle.shape("turtle")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
print("Hi")
```

When I run this I get this output:

```
2023-06-18 13:08:23.720 Python[71369:2018591] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
```

What do I do?

I am expecting hi to be printed but nothing happens.

Comment: Move the print earlier, e.g. to the top. Can you see its output?

Comment: I had this problem after installing Sonoma while running a Tkinter app using my mac's default 3.10 python. After using Brew to install the latest python and brew install python-tk to install the latest tkinter I can now run the app fine.

Comment: See [sonoma and NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283578/sonoma-and-nsapplicationdelegate-applicationsupportssecurerestorablestate)

Answer (score 3):

The message you mentioned, "WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES," appears to be related to macOS-specific functionality and doesn't affect the execution of your code.

Regarding the issue where "Hi" is not being printed, the problem lies in the order of your code. You're calling screen.exitonclick() before printing "Hi," so the program exits immediately without giving you a chance to see the output.

To fix this, you can reorder your code as follows:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy_the_turtle = Turtle()
timmy_the_turtle.shape("turtle")

print("Hi")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

With this change, the output "Hi" should be printed before the program exits.

Comment: is there a fix for this secure coding message? Can't find anything online about it... it affects pygame, turtle tkinter and more as far as I can tell. Do we just wait ?

Comment: The language here looks awfully like ChatGPT.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to see 'Hi' printed in the console, you should move the
print("Hi") statement before the screen.exitonclick(). The program ends before you get to see the 'Hi' So, like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy_the_turtle = Turtle()

timmy_the_turtle.shape("turtle")

print("Hi")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This is identical to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76502779/6243352). Please make sure you're adding something new when you post an answer, otherwise it just pollutes the thread with redundant information (although, to its credit, it's not a ChatGPT answer).