# sonoma and NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jmeter, java-11, macos-sonoma

On Sonoma 14.0, I am receiving the following when trying to launch JMeter or using Intellij both with OpenJdk@11, @17 or @21.  I would like some help resolving this:  WARNING: Secure coding is automatically enabled for restorable state! However, not on all supported macOS versions of this application. Opt-in to secure coding explicitly by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:.

Answer (score 8):

### TLDR:

1. If you are not customizing how your app saves/restores state, you should implement this method and return `true`.
2. If you ARE customizing how your app saves/restores state (via `NSApplicationDelegate's application(_, willEncodeRestorableState:)` and related methods), you should verify that you use `NSSecureCoding` for all that work and then *still* implement this method and return `true`.
3. Not implementing this method or implementing it and returning `false` leaves your app (and your users' Macs) vulnerable.

### Summary:

There is a vulnerability in the way macOS records and restores the “saved state” of an application. By default, this save/restore process does not use `NSSecureCoding` because the process was added to macOS before secure coding existed.

Because the process does not use `NSSecureCoding`, an attacker can very carefully manipulate the saved state data on disk to hijack the restoration process, escalate to full root user permission, and even overcome the SIP (system integrity protection) features of macOS. All of that is what security experts call “bad”.

Apple could not simply switch the process to use `NSSecureCoding` because third-party developers might be customizing how their apps save state and those customizations might not use Secure Coding, so *forcing* the switch would break apps.

The best Apple could do was offer this new API: allow developers to explicitly tell AppKit, “You can use Secure Coding for saving and restoring state; I’m not doing any custom stuff during that process that’s incompatible with `NSSecureCoding`.”

### Full Details:

https://sector7.computest.nl/post/2022-08-process-injection-breaking-all-macos-security-layers-with-a-single-vulnerability/

### Note:

As a user, you can't resolve this warning. You'll need to file an issue with the developer of the affected apps and point them to the information above. They'll need to update their apps to resolve the warning.