# Python Error message in pycharm, am unsure what it means

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've run this program before and it has worked with all blocks appearing on the page and the white one being manipulated and moved by my WASD keys. But now all I get is this error message that I have no idea what's asking. Error code: (2024-01-28 16:35:33.648 Python[39376:3003605] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.)

For the program to run with a black screen, red blocks, and a white one that I can move.

code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Game")
wn.bgcolor("Black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=800)
wn.tracer(0)

# paddle a
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(0, -300)
```

Im using a MacBook Pro 14.2.1

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77320845/6394617)?