Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState
i'm coding a program using java and javaFx on IntelliJ
i have a macbook with macOS Sonoma 14.4
when i run the code with maven i have this issue:
WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES. Exception in Application start method
Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
i searched online for possible solutions but i didn't find any

Is there a stack trace associated with the exception? If so, post it in its entirety in the question, formatted as a code block (not inline code). If not, you need to run the application in a way that gives you the complete stack trace. Add the code that causes the exception.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283578/sonoma-and-nsapplicationdelegate-applicationsupportssecurerestorablestate. Basically, this would appear to be an issue between the JDK and MacOS. Make sure you have the latest version of the JDK and that it is the correct one for your platform. As far as I can tell, the warning is not preventing your code from running though; that is caused by issues in your code and you haven't posted either the code or the error message.

The warning is coming from core MacOS. The warning is not related directly to Java or JavaFX. People are getting the same warning while working on other technologies like Python or Unreal Engine. It's due to interfering with the MacOS core components.
I got this error and wrote an article on that too. Here is the article link: Reason: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES

This is a resolved issue, use an appropriate JavaFX version (21.0.2+).
Additionally, as recommended in comments:

Make sure you have the latest version of the JDK and that it is the correct one for your platform.

