# Python turtle screen doesn't open on my computer

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to get an assignment done for my class and I have to use the turtle library in python the only problem is when I try to run this code the screen appears for 1 second the disappears. When I return back to my IDE i have this error message
`WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.`

I tried looking it up but couldn't find a solution. I don't know if this helps but IM using VSCODE as well.
The following is the code I'm running

```
import turtle

# today we are learning about turtle and creating graphics for gui
# always need to add a screen
myScreen = turtle.Screen()

# this is the pen
myPen = turtle.Turtle()

myPen.forward(100)
```

Comment: Try adding `turtle.exitonclick()` at the end of the program. Possible dupe of [Python Turtle Graphics Window only Opens Briefly then Closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018243/python-turtle-graphics-window-only-opens-briefly-then-closes), [Turtle graphics - How do I control when the window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234798/turtle-graphics-how-do-i-control-when-the-window-closes), also [When I run my code I get a weird output (listed in question). What do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502383)