# Python Turtle Screen not showing up

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Does anyone know why the screen isn't popping up? I put the myScreen function above it pops but it isn't working. Is this a problem with my ide?

```
import turtle



color = input("What color: ")
linewidth = int(input("What linewidth: "))  
linelength = int(input("What linelength: "))  
shape = input("line, triangle, or square: ")
myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myScreen = turtle.Screen()

if shape == "line":
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.width(linewidth)
    myTurtle.forward(linelength)
elif shape == "triangle":
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.width(linewidth)
    for _ in range(3):
        myTurtle.forward(linelength)
        myTurtle.left(120)
elif shape == "square":
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.width(linewidth)
    for _ in range(4):
        myTurtle.forward(linelength)
        myTurtle.left(90)
else:
    print("Shape not recognized.")
```

Comment: Add `turtle.exitonclick()` as the last line in your program. Common problem: [Python turtle screen doesn't open on my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77942149/python-turtle-screen-doesnt-open-on-my-computer?noredirect=1#comment137409234_77942149), [Python Turtle Graphics Window only Opens Briefly then Closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018243/python-turtle-graphics-window-only-opens-briefly-then-closes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, it turns out that you have not used `turtle.done()` in your code. This is the fixed code:

```
import turtle

color = input("What color: ")
linewidth = int(input("What linewidth: "))  
linelength = int(input("What linelength: "))  
shape = input("line, triangle, or square: ")
myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myScreen = turtle.Screen()

if shape == "line":
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.width(linewidth)
    myTurtle.forward(linelength)
elif shape == "triangle":
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.width(linewidth)
    for _ in range(3):
        myTurtle.forward(linelength)
        myTurtle.left(120)
elif shape == "square":
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.width(linewidth)
    for _ in range(4):
        myTurtle.forward(linelength)
        myTurtle.left(90)
else:
    print("Shape not recognized.")

turtle.done()
```

This alternative is better than the one suggested in the comments of the post: `turtle.exitonclick()`, while it does the job, it also closes the program on a click. turtle.done() is a alias for turtle.mainloop().